# Как получить рандомное число из сложного промежутка?

Tags: c#

Есть промежуток такого вида: От -1.5f до -0.5f и от 0.5f до 1.5f.
Нужно получить рандомное число из такого диапазона, проще говоря нужно число от -1.5f до 1.5f, но выключив такой промежуток : от -0.5f до 0.5f

Comment: Вот прямо так симметрично, или интервалы могут быть разной длины (напр. от -2 до -1 и от 1 до 3)? И может ли интервалов быть больше двух?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Почему бы не так:

```
double result;
double raw = random.NextDouble();
if (raw < 0.5) // raw in [0, 0.5)
   result = raw * 2 - 1.5; // raw * 2 in [0, 1), result in [-1.5, -0,5)
else           // raw in [0.5, 1)
   result = raw * 2 - 0.5; // raw * 2 in [1, 2), result in [0.5, 1.5)
```

Если вам нужно, к примеру, (0.5, 1.5] вместо [0.5, 1.5), можно «перевернуть» результат:

```
   result = 2.5 - raw * 2; // -raw * 2 in (-2, -1], result in (0.5, 1.5]
```

Если вам нужен именно `float`, можно объявить `result` как `float` и скастить при присвоении.

---

В переменной `random` должен быть экземпляр класса `Random`. Для .NET Framework имеет смысл завести глобальный экземпляр ([тут](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Random) объяснение, почему), а для .NET Core и .NET 5+ можно создать прямо в начале метода:

```
var random = new Random();
```

Comment: `float` вроде нужен же ) хотя, автор не указал

Comment: @aepot: Кстати да

Comment: Не могу понять что такое ```random``` из второй строки в этом случае?

Comment: @SuddenDumb перед кодом напишите `Random random = new Random();` Только учтите, что создать `random` вам надо один раз, а не каждый раз при генерации числа, иначе это будет работать не эффективно.

Comment: `а для .NET Core и .NET 5+` - [вот не знал](https://drewjcooper.github.io/coding/2019/09/13/misusing-system-random-dotnet-core.html), спасибо!

Comment: @aepot: Пожалуйста! Я даже когда-то [затребовал](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/3764) внести этот факт в документацию, а [@MSDN.WhiteKnight](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240512/msdn-whiteknight) таки [внёс](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/3855).

Comment: Результат разве не принадлежит `[-1.5; -0.5)` и `[0.5; 1.5)` соотвественно?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Вы правы, уточнил в коде. Дописал ещё вариант с переворотом.